# Why is this code preventing my app from closing?

Tags: c#, .net

Make a WinForms application in Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.0, then make a user control (from *Project/Add User Control...*) with this code:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    private string _SelectedTable;

    public string SelectedTable
    {
        get { return _SelectedTable; }
        set { _SelectedTable = value; }
    }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataBindings.Add("SelectedTable", listBox1, "SelectedValue");
        listBox1.DataSource = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Compile, add the control from the tool box to `Form1`, compile again and try to close. It won't (right?). Why?

There are things I can do to prevent this from happening, like changing the line `DataBindings.Add("SelectedTable", listBox1, "SelectedValue");` to `DataBindings.Add("SelectedTable", tablesListBox, "SelectedValue", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);`, or removing any of the two lines after `InitializeComponent()`. But I would like to know why is this happening, or at least, what is in general what I'm doing wrong, the general rule I'm breaking so I don't make a similar mistake again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's some kind of validation issue... If you set `CausesValidation` to false on the user control, it works fine. Not sure what's going on exactly, though...

Anyway, if you're not explicitly setting the `ValueMember` property, the `SelectedValue` isn't meaningful, you should use `SelectedItem` instead. I tried your code with `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`, and it works fine.

Comment: Well, `SelectedValue.ToString()` gives me whatever text is selected in the list, same as `SelectedItem.ToString()`. I guess I'll use `SelectedItem` though since it seems to be the convention.

Comment: I agree that it *should* work with `SelectedValue` but apparently it doesn't... Perhaps you should file a bug on Microsoft Connect, because I don't see any logical explanation for this behavior.

Comment: Actually, it has to be a bug since as you say there is no logical connection, nothing throws an exception and there is no __'Note'__ in Microsoft's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be couse you never said what SelectedValue is bound to...
I changed your code like so and it works:

```
Collection<Person> mylist = new Collection<Person>();            
listBox1.DataSource = mylist;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
listBox1.ValueMember = "ID";

DataBindings.Add("SelectedTable", listBox1, "SelectedValue");
```